# Uncaught ReferenceError: changeImportant is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Я делаю простую todo программу с помощью vue.js,
при запуске программа выдаёт ошибку: Todo.html:125 Uncaught ReferenceError: changeImportant is not defined
Помогите исправить и объясните пожалуйста, что не так.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            body{
                margin: 0;
                font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
                font-size: 18px;
                color:#35495e;
            }

            .container{
                width: 700px;
                margin: auto;
            }

            ul{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style: none;
            }

        li{
                display: block;
                border: 2px solid #41b782;
                margin: 10px 0;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            li:hover{
                background: #5cb88f33;
            }
        
            textarea, input[type="text"]{
                padding: 5px 2px;
                width: 400px;
                border: 1px solid #35495e;
                border-radius: 5px;
                
                font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="container" id="app">
            <h4>Новая заметка:</h4>
            <input id="input" type="text" size="40">
                <button v-on:click="addElement()">Добавить!</button>
                
            <h2>Дела на сегодня:</h2>
            
            
            <table>
                <li v-for="item in todo">
                    {{ item.name }}
                    <br><br>
                    
                    <input id=getRangeID() type="range" step="1" min="1" max="3" list="rangeList" value="1" oninput="changeImportant(item.id,this.value)">
    <!--                <input id=getRangeID() type="range" step="1" min="1" max="3" list="rangeList" value="1" oninput="todo[item.id-1].importance=this.value;">-->
                    <datalist id="rangeList">
                    <option value="1" label="1">
                    <option value="2" label="2">
                    <option value="3" label="3">
                    </datalist>
                    Важность дела:
                    <span>{{ item.importance }}</span>
                    
            </table>
               
               
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            var text;
            new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    todo:[
                          {id: 1, importance: 1, name: 'Решить ДЗ'},
                          {id: 2, importance: 1, name: 'Изучить документацию Vue.js'},
                          {id: 3, importance: 2, name: 'Сварить макароны'},
                          {id: 4, importance: 2, name: 'Купить молоко'},
                          {id: 5, importance: 3, name: 'Перейти на Linux'},
                    ],
                },
                    methods: {
                        addElement(){
                            text = document.getElementById("input").value;
                            if(text!=""){
                                this.todo.push({id: this.todo.length+1, name: text, importance: 1});
                                document.getElementById("input").value = "";
                            }
                        },
                        changeImportant(id,value){
                            this.todo[id-1].importance=value;
                        }
                    }
                    
            })
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 1. `oninput` ➝ `@input`; 2. выражение `this.value` пытается получить `value` из `data` - тут либо использовать `v-model`, либо инпут обернуть в компонент и передавать значение корневому экземпляру Vue через событие.

Comment: ...компоненты конечно предпочтительнее (т.к. они более удобно организуют общую логику приложения), но и `v-model` на самом деле неплохой вариант, когда элементов ввода мало.